# Divisibility exercises

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p>2$ be a prime number and $n\in\{1,2,\dots, p-2\}$. I have to prove that $p$ does not divide $2^{n}-1$. Any idea? I have tried using the Fermat's theorem, which says that $p$ divides $2^{p}-1$, but I don't get anywhere...

Comment: Actually in Fermat's theorem the power is $p-1$ to get $1.$ That is, if gcd(a,p)=1 then $a^{p-1}-1$ is divisible by $p.$

Answer (score 1):

If $p=7$ the allowable $n$ are 1,2,3,4,5 but $7$ divides $2^3-1.$

Answer (score 0):

The result does not hold. Let $p=7$ and $n=3$. There are infinitely many other examples.

Added: If $p$ is a prime $\gt 3$ for which $2$ is not a primitive root, then there is an $n$ between $1$ and $p-2$ such that $p$ divides $2^n-1$. In particular, this is the case whenever $2$ is a quadratic residue of $p$. Thus every prime of the form $8k\pm 1$ provides a counterexample. There are others.